# DateTimePicker spits calender beneath the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, date, time

I got a problem with my DateTimePicker. You can see the problem in the image down here. The calender and strings are just placed beneath my login page when I logout. Also in the rest of my pages they are created at the bottom of the page. Does somebody have the same problem? or does anyone know how to fix this?

Already a big thanks.

[image: The calender is just randomly created in the left conrner]

Comment: Can you share the code, using jsfiddle or plunker

Comment: Did you include the css?

Comment: I do include the css. What code do you want? Because I already searched for things that could be wrong in the code but I couldn't find any. When I inspect the element I see that a random <div> is created. When I delete that <div> the calender disappears.

Comment: Included the wrong css.. You are a hero!